# Implement click event on Apexchart title

Tags: vuejs3, apexcharts

I'm using apexcharts in Vue3, and want to let the user edit the chart title, which should be initiated by the user clicking the title. I have the general apexchart click event working, but unsure how to identify if the click happens within the title area.

Do I need to calculate the location of the title and compare it with the location of the click, or is there a simpler method to identify the section of the chart that was clicked?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the apexcharts click event, you can check if the MouseEvent have `apexcharts-title-text` class like this

```
events: {
  click: function(event) {
    if([...event.target.classList].includes('apexcharts-title-text')){
      alert('Title clicked')
    }
  }
}
```